# Nginx not working with Docker, Django and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I've been struggling to Dockerize an existing Django app for over a week now and I'm a bit out of ideas how to proceed. I've copied the prod environment and environment setup but I'm still struggling with the last part that is related to Nginx. I'll outline my Docker files and the YML file that brings the app to life. The Django app, the SQL DB, the Redis instance and the CRON server are all working but the last piece of the puzzle is the Nginx container.

The `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  xyz_web:
    image: xyz-web:latest
    networks:
      - xyz_backend
    volumes:
      - ../app:/app
      - xyz_static:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - xyz_db
      - xyz_cache
    # ports:
    #   - 8000:8000
    command: gunicorn xyz_src.wsgi:application --bind :8000 --workers 1 --threads=3 --access-logfile -
    env_file:
      - django/.env

  xyz_cron:
    image: xyz-web:latest
    networks:
      - xyz_backend
    volumes:
      - ../app:/app
    depends_on:
      - xyz_db
      - xyz_cache
    command: cron -f
    env_file:
      - django/.env
  
  xyz_cache:
    image: xyz-cache:latest
    networks:
      - xyz_backend
    volumes:
      - ../build/redis/data:/data
    command: /bin/sh -c "redis-server --requirepass $$REDIS_CACHE_PASS"
    env_file:
      - redis/.env

  xyz_db:
    image: xyz-db:latest
    networks:
      - xyz_backend
    volumes:
      - ../build/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ../build/mysql/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    env_file:
      - mysql/.env
      
  xyz_proxy:
    image: xyz-proxy:latest
    networks:
      - xyz_backend
    volumes:
      - xyz_static:/app/static
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - xyz_web

networks:
  xyz_backend:
    external: false
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  xyz_static:
```

The `Dockerfile` for the `Django` app is:

```
FROM python:3.10.13-bullseye

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# update and upgrade the image
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install cron -y

# install TA-Lib dependency
RUN set -x \
    && wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf ./ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz \
    && cd ta-lib \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install

# upgrade the pip package manager
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

ADD app /app

COPY build/django/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# EXPOSE 8000
```

The `Dockerfile` for the `SQL` DB is:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.34-debian

# update and upgrade the image
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y

CMD ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci", "--skip-character-set-client-handshake"]

WORKDIR /app
```

The `Dockerfile` for the `Redis` instance is:

```
FROM redis:6.2.13-bookworm

# update and upgrade the image
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y

COPY build/redis/etc/redis /etc/redis
```

And finally the `Dockerfile` for the `Nginx` proxy is:

```
FROM nginx:1.25.2-bookworm

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY build/nginx/etc/nginx/conf.d/prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

EXPOSE 80
```

The `prod.conf` is:

```
upstream prod_server {
    server xyz_web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://prod_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /app/staticfiles;
    }
}
```

The issue is that Nginx is not serving traffic on port 80 over localhost but I can still use the app at port 8000. I'm not sure what I'm missing and any hints to what's wrong would be greatly appreciated. I've also setup Nginx to serve the static traffic but I don't know whether it's working since the proxy seems not to be running even if all containers report to be working. I've exec-ed into them to confirm that the files are there and they seem to look good:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                               NAMES
c0acefca3fdd   xyz-proxy:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   32 hours ago   Up 32 hours   0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp                build-xyz_proxy-1
ee40391a2259   xyz-web:latest     "gunicorn xyz_sr…"       32 hours ago   Up 32 hours                                       build-xyz_web-1
5b47db517201   xyz-web:latest     "cron -f"                32 hours ago   Up 32 hours                                       build-xyz_cron-1
d93d5e1c568b   xyz-db:latest      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   32 hours ago   Up 32 hours   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   build-xyz_db-1
b944a33ea68a   xyz-cache:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   32 hours ago   Up 32 hours   6379/tcp                            build-xyz_cache-1
```

Comment: Fix proposed by @Mess resolved the port 80 issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your are correct in mentioning that nginx is serving the app on port  8000 and not on 80. According to your nginx configuration on docker-compose

```
ports:
  - 8000:80
```

The left side represents the port on the `host machine` and the right side is the port inside the `container`. So your app is not being served on port `80`, its served on port `8000`. To serve it on port `80` on the host machine change 8000 to 80 as well. Also make sure that port 80 is available on the host machine and you have no services using it. If its not available, you will have to shut down those services.

Your ports mapping for nginx should be:

```
ports:
    - 80:80
```